# What is JavaCameraView used for?

Tags: java, android, opencv, view, camera

Dears

I have browsed the net but have not found such eye-catching info regarding JavaCameraView.

I know JavaCameraView extends CameraBridgeViewBase but I have not understood the necessity of JavaCameraView.

1-What privileges does JavaCameraView have that make it a better option compared to CameraBridgeViewBase?

2- When do we use JavaCameraView and when CameraBridgeViewBase?

3- I have seen the usage of JavaCameraView in the XML file as a layout. What is this then?

```
 <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:visibility="gone"
 android:id="@+id/HelloOpenCvView"
 opencv:show_fps="true"
 opencv:camera_id="any" />
```

4- the following code is written once using JavaCameraView a and once CameraBridgeViewBase. what is the difference?
private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
 setContentView(R.layout.HelloOpenCvLayout);
 mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) 
 findViewById(R.id.HelloOpenCvView);
 mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
 mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
```

}

V.S

```
   mCameraView = new JavaCameraView(this, mCameraIndex);
   mCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(size.width, size.height);
   mCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
   setContentView(mCameraView);
```

Sorry for the length of my question, but you could lift such a heavy weight off my shoulder.
Best

Comment: Well, JavaCameraView is an implementation of the abstract class CameraBridgeViewBase.

Comment: @jvrodrigues would you please my question number 4 for me to clarify. Because in the first piece of codes mOpenCvCameraView, an instance of CameraBridgeViewBase, has done the job and JavaCameraView was only used in the XML file for layout.

Comment: @jvrodrigues  can you help?

Comment: its an instance of CameraBridgeViewBase but its also an instance of JavaCameraView. Because JavaCameraView is a CameraBridgeViewBase extension. Please read about inheritance in java, classes, subclasses and overall oop.